# Using unix paste command to print array elements side by side?

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, paste

Lets say I have an array consisting of many multiline string variables:

```sh
array[1] = "aaa      
            aaa
            aaa"

array[2] = "bbb
            bbb
            bbb"

array[3] = "ccc
            ccc
            ccc"
```

and so on.

And I want to print them side by side like so:

```sh
aaa    bbb    ccc    ddd    eee
aaa    bbb    ccc    ddd    eee    ...    etc.
aaa    bbb    ccc    ddd    eee
```

Using `paste` works perfectly in this case because other methods I tried didn't have good formatting, except I have to write out every array element manually:

```sh
paste <(echo -e "${array[1]}") <(echo -e "${array[2]}") <(echo -e "${array[3]}")
```

and so on.

Is there any way to loop over every element in `array` and print them side by side using `paste`? If not, is there an alternative method I could use for this task?

Comment: Is the number of lines per element known in advance? Is the number of elements in the array known in advance?

Comment: `paste` runs a single time in your example, so no, you can't accomplish this with a loop. If you are trying to ask if there is a way to generate thet command line with a loop, then certainly yes (it's just strings after all) but this seems rather tortured. Is there a way to store your data in a different arrangement so you don't have to? With Bash 5 you could use nested arrays.

Comment: Please use valid bash syntax to show the array.

Comment: Is your question of how to do this with an unknown number of columns? It is not really clear...

Comment: No, the number of lines per element is not known in advance. This is also for an unknown amount of elements (i.e. columns) in the array. The answer by @thanasisp solves this with ```"${arr[@]}"```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with a loop. But of course, you call `paste` multiple times, once per item.

```
arr=("aaa\naaa\naaa" "bbb\nbbb\nbbb" "ccc\nccc\nccc")

tmp=""
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
    tmp=$(paste -d' ' <(echo -e "$tmp") <( echo -e "$x"))
done

echo -e "$tmp"
```

I kept your existing `echo -e` command, but please have a look into this good read: [Why is printf better than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819) . As pointed by @Charles Duffy, `printf "%b\n"` is the POSIX-compliant way for your task.

Comment: Your sample data is quite unlike the OP's, insofar as they have literal newlines in their input while you have two-character backslash-n sequences and are relying on `echo -e` to interpret them. (`echo -e` is a bad idea in general: it's disallowed by POSIX, so bash breaks the standard by having it enabled; _because_ it breaks the standard, bash has flags that can be set to turn it off, and those flags can be set through environment variables, so if you don't control the environment your script runs in, you don't know `echo -e` will work at all!)

Comment: ...the POSIX-compliant way to interpret backslash-escape sequences while printing a string with a trailing newline is `printf '%b\n' "$tmp"`. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and Stephane's excellent answer to the [unix.se] question [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113)

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for the detailed comment! It is very useful. The goal of the existing answer is to modify OP's existing command to a while-loop for the array. I do not know if my sample data is not like OP's. (OP is not using valid bash syntax to show array declaration, but some pseudo-code Still pending is my request to show the declaration). But I know OP's `echo -e` command is working as expected, so the above loop is expected to work too! Also, `<(...)` is not POSIX-compliant, I do not mention that but in my random environment I had to `bash` it, not `sh` it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info guys. This loop works perfectly. I knew that `printf` has more functionality than `echo` but I was using the latter because its more popular I guess, but I didn't know that `echo -e` is disallowed by POSIX. I looked at that Unix Stack Exchange post and will be using `printf` in the future. Also I am aware that `<(...)` is not POSIX-compliant but `paste` suits my needs perfectly and its not really a big deal to me :P.